# Adding await to fs.writeFileSync is not working in a readline question (Node 10.11.0)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, readline, fs

Note: I am using the readline module in this code and the code that isn't working is in a `rl.question` statement.

I am trying to add an await statement to my fs.writeFileSync but any time I run the program the await function just doesn't work, like the await function isn't even there. It doesn't show any errors in the console and it only writes to the file wanted after the `rl.question` is closed.

I have tried promisifying the code, and I have tried making a seperate variable for question 2 because i currently have 2 questions in one readline interface.

**javascript**

```
rl.question('Type discord invite here: ', async (invite) => {
    console.log(`${invite} is a bout to get pooed`);
    const invites = {
        "inviteCode": `${invite}`
    }
    const inviteJSON = JSON.stringify(invites)
    await fs.writeFileSync("code.json", inviteJSON);
// I want this file to get written before the next question gets asked but it only writes after the second question is asked
r1.question('Type what you want the bot to say (Less than 2000 characters): ', async (mess) => {
        const messa = {
            "mess": `${mess}`
        }
        console.log(code.inviteCode) // this is supposed to be the new string that was supposed to be set before the second question but it just outputs as the JSON contents that I manually put in.   
        const messJSON = JSON.stringify(messa)
        await fs.writeFileSync("message.json", messJSON);
        console.log("Invite code set.....")
        fs.readdir("./bots", (err, botfiles) => {
            if(err) console.error(err)

            let bots = botfiles.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");

            bots.forEach((f, i) => {
                require(`./bots/${f}`);
                console.log(`${i + 1} bots loading.`);
            });
        });
        r1.close();
    });
});
```

I expect that the file is written to before the second question but in reality it gets written after the second question is answered.

Comment: `writeFileSync` is *synchronous*, as the name says. `await`ing it is pointless?!

Comment: I have tried removing the await ofc it comes out as the same result

Comment: How exactly do you know the file is written only after the second question is answered?

Comment: Because I log the file contents after the first question and after the second question.

Comment: You mean the `console.log(code.inviteCode)`? Where is `code` even defined?

Comment: `code` is defined at the very top of my code you can see it but its: `const code = require("./code.json");` and code.json has inviteCode in it which is what I write the file to

Comment: Well if you require the json *before* you write to the file, then it should be obvious that you got the old object. Changing a file doesn't magically let your application re-evaluate it.

Comment: Yes, i tried requiring it again and it didnt work.

Comment: `require`ing it *again* gets you the cached value, which the module evaluated to on the first run. You would need to clear the cache first, but I recommend to avoid that. What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)? Why not just use the `invites` object that you already created in your application - why do you want to serialise it to JSON, write it to a file, and read it back from there?